# Interaction of inlining and inheritance for the JVM

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm, inline, jit

Will the JIT inline a call in an inherited method of an abstract class which is megamorphic across all sub-classes but monomorphic for a given sub-class?

Suppose we have an interface `IFace` with numerous implementations `A` through `Z`.  Suppose also we have an abstract class `Foo` which holds a field of type `IFace` and calls a method on that field in its only method (which is `final`) and that we have many sub-classess of `Foo`, all of which do nothing, like this (constructors omitted for brevity):

```
interface IFace {
   void act();
}

final class A extends IFace {
    ...
}

...

final class Z extends IFace {
    ...
}

abstract class Foo {
    final IFace field;

    public final void doAThing() {
        field.act();
    }
}

final class FooA extends Foo {
}

 ...

final class FooZ extends Foo {
}
```

Suppose 'by accident' all instances of `FooX` in fact have `field` values of the corresponding type `X`.  Suppose further we have code like this in a very hot spot:

```
for (final Foo foo : foos) {
    foo.doAThing();
}
```

where `foos` is of type `List<Foo>`, is large, and contains a random and roughly uniform distribution of all sub-classes of `Foo`.

The `foo.doAThing()` call site is very megamorphic, so no inlining can occur.  But when determining whether `field.act()` can be inlined within `doAThing`, is type-profiling done per-subclass or just for `Foo` as a whole?  If per sub-class, we would have 26 versions of `doAThing`, each of which's call to `field.act()` is monomorphic and inlineable, but if we have only one, the call to `field.act()` would be megamorphic and not inlineable.

(I know the answer to this may be JDK-specific, so I am asking in particular for recent versions of OpenJDK)

Comment: probably yes. The `field.act()` *might* be inlined. But there is no guarantee. The answer to all your questions is - *depending on JVM / hotspot version and state*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profile data is collected per method. Given that `doAThing()` is final in your case, there is only one method for all subclasses. Thus the profile for `field.act()` is likely to be spoiled by other Foos if `doAThing()` is actually called for them many times.

Currently (as of JDK8u60) type profiles do not take the context into account.
There is a bug report [JDK-8015416](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015416) to fix this some time in future.

Answer (score 0):

The profiling is an act of analyzing the runtime *behavior* of a program, not of its code. So its not “done per-subclass” and its not done “for `Foo` as a whole” as neither makes sense.

Just image that the JVM peeks into the call stacks of the active threads regularly to see what concrete method they are actually executing and what concrete method has called them. The stack inspection may even go up some more stack frames, but it’s usually limited to a certain number of frames to cut down the cost of the inspection.

This analysis already provides the two necessary information, whether there is a dominant call target, if not even a monomorphic behavior, and which method it is. Therefore it doesn’t matter how many alternative implementations exist, as long as they are rarely invoked.

Optimizing based on this information also implies that the JVM takes care to detect if the behavior of the program changes and the optimized code has to get de-optimized, if not replaced by a differently optimized variant.

It’s also helpful that JVMs know, which classes have ever been instantiated (and usually even won’t load classes prior to their first use). So if there is only one implementation class for an `interface` at runtime, a monomorphic behavior will be assumed without the need to wait for the profiler to prove it. Since the JVM knows when a new subclass/implementation class gets loaded, it can de-optimize in time.